# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined error on clicking on an object

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have created a function in protractor using javascript. The function returns an index value of an element on the web page:

```
this.selectIndexofSandbox = function (displayName) {

  return element(by.id('troposSandboxListPanel')).all(by.tagName('a')).then(function (allLinks) {
    var index;
    for (let i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {

      return allLinks[i].getText().then(function (text) {

        if (text.indexOf(displayName) !== -1) {
          console.log('The value of i at this juncture is ' + i);
          //this.indexOFSandbox = i;
          index = i;
          console.log('The index of the required sandbox is ' + index);
          return index;
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I am using the same function and getting the index value and using the same in the call back function.

```
tce_apps_page.selectIndexofSandbox(sandboxDisplayName)
  .then((index) => {
    tce_apps_page.selectSandbox(index);
  })
```

In the function selectIndexofSandbox, the value of the index is shown to be 2. But when invoked in the callback function, the index is showing as 'undefined'. 
Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: Can you also include the code for `selectSandbox`. This is likely where the issue lies

Comment: ` this.selectSandbox = function(index){
  
  return element(by.id('troposSandboxListPanel')).all(by.tagName('a')).then(function(allLinks){
   console.log('The index in the selectSandbox function  is '+index);
   return allLinks[this.index].click();
  })
 }
 `

Comment: Your issue is here `allLinks[this.index].click()`. There should be no need to use `this.` before calling your index variable. To better understand the this keyword check out [this medium article](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8)